# Azure Mobile Services Authentication Error

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-mobile-services

I have created a Mobile Service application, and deployed the default template to Azure. When I try to access it prompts me with a Windows Authentication popup.

I have then configured it to use the Azure Active Directory (according to the documentation here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-active-directory-authentication/ and here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-xamarin-ios-get-started-users/#add-authentication) by adding an application to the AD and specified client-id's. and app uri's between the two and set the domain as tenant for the Mobile Service. I also installed Backend Security and set AzureActiveDirectoryExtendedLoginProvider as login provider in the backend.

However, it still prompts me with the Windows Authentication popup, but now when I go to .azure-mobile.net/login/aad it sends me to the Active Directory login page as expected, but with the following error

```
AADSTS70001: Application with identifier xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx was not found in the directory yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy
```

The application identifier is the correct identifier, but the directory identifier does not belong to my active directory, which is the only directory I have and which is configured as tenant in the mobile service. When I try to login to the mobile service from a mobile application it just gives me a blank page.

I also tried creating another AD with a different domain/tenant, but it still gives the same directory guid in the error message.